# Connect to remote Express API from Postman

Tags: express, postman, remote-access, vps

I am trying to connect to my API, hosted on a remote VPS, via Postman but can't seem to find any definitive guides on how to do it.

The VPS has a frontend app (Vue) that connects to Express using Nginx reverse proxy. That works fine.

However, I want to share some of the Express API with another client not hosted on the same server. For example, connecting from Postman with user authentication to just share data in JSON format.

If anyone can give me any advice on how to achieve this I would much appreciate it.

**EDIT**

Here is an example request I am trying from Postman. Express is confirmed running on 3001 on the VPS.

```
http://vps-url:3001/test
```

This is the corresponding route in Express

```
app.get("/test", (req,res)=>{
 res.json({ msg: 'Hello from VPS!' })
})
```

When I try to access in Postman, is just hangs.

I have also this CORS config to allow connection from my local machine using my public IP.

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    const corsWhitelist = [
        'http://vps-url.com',
        'https://anotherclient',
        '70.80.xxx.xxx' // my machine IP 
    ];
    if (corsWhitelist.indexOf(req.headers.origin) !== -1) {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
    }
    next();
});
```

Comment: By sharing you mean another frontend cosumer hosted in a different machine? Can you clarify a bit more? Is it another frontend that can't access your API or it's also inaccessible via Postman?

Comment: @n1md7 No I don't have another frontend as such. I just want to be able to connect to my remote Express server to retrieve data from the API like I would using Postman with local Express/Mongo app hosted. Thanks for repsone.

Comment: When you send request via postman what is exactly not working?

Comment: @n1md7 Postman request just hangs. I have added more code to my question. Hope that makes it easier to understand. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see any specific problem in your setup. Dev tools like Postman usually don't care about the CORs. However, if this is a case why don't you use [CORS middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html) instead? Also, can you post the CURL command Postman sends?

Comment: @n1md7 OK. I'll look further into it. Thanks for the advice.